# Why does filtering a new JSON object causes the old one to self-update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON array named **arr** and a new array named **new_arr** that is created from **arr**.

```
var arr = {"data":
 [
  {"name":"Alan","height":"171","weight":"66"},
  {"name":"Ben","height":"182","weight":"90"},
  {"name":"Chris","height":"163","weight":"71"}
 ]
};

var new_arr = arr;

new_arr.data = jQuery.grep(new_arr.data, function(n, i){
  return n.weight > 70;
});
```

Both arrays **arr** and **new_arr** becomes:

```
{"data":
 [
  {"name":"Ben","height":"182","weight":"90"},
  {"name":"Chris","height":"163","weight":"71"}
 ]
};
```

My question is: "**Why does modifying the new array changes the old one?**"

Comment: I don't see any JSON in your code, only JavaScript objects.

Comment: It is a JSON object obtained from $getJSON method. I cut out and simplified the code here.

Comment: Ok, but even then, the problem is not related to JSON but to how array and object references are handled in JavaScript.

Comment: I have tried with linear array and the old array didn't change using `var new_arr = arr`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no **new array**. It's just a new reference to the old array.
Try it in another example :

```
var a = {};
var b = a;
// check to see if they are equal
alert(a === b);
// modify one of them 
b.foo = 'bar';
 // check to see if they are equal
alert(a === b);
// modify one of them 
a.bar = 'foo';
 // check to see if they are equal
alert(a === b);
```

`a` and `b` refer to the same object, thus, when you modify `a` you also modify `b` and so on.

If you use jquery you should use the `extend` method :

```
var new_arr = $.extend(true,arr);
```

Comment: sorry, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

You're referencing the same Array when you do:

```
var new_arr = arr;
```

If you want a copy, you need to make a copy:

```
var new_arr = arr.data.slice( 0 ); // 0 is the optional starting index of the copy
```

This just makes a shallow copy of the Array, so the nested objects will be referenced by both.

If you need a deep clone of all nested objects, you'd need to traverse into each individual object, and make a copy.

Comment: I'm curious whether passing `0` is recommended? `arr.slice()` should work as well or are there any issues in certain browsers I'm not aware of?

Comment: @FelixKling: No, it's not needed since `0` is default, and I don't know of any browser issues. I just thought I had better be a little more explicit in this case. Added a code comment to clarify. :)

Comment: Ok, I just saw many people doing this recently and was wondering... :) Thanks!

Comment: just because he named it `arr`, it doesn't make it an array. It's actually an object, and calling `slice` on it would trigger an error.

Comment: I need a deep copy. The extend method works perfectly. Thanks for your suggestion too :)

Comment: @gion: I assume patrick was confused by the description, where it says *JSON array*.

Comment: Yes, I didn't look closely enough. Updated my answer.

Comment: @Felix Kling : I wasn't being mean, but I assumed that as confused as he may have been, he would've just copy/paste the code and return to SO with an error msg

Comment: @gion: I know, I know :) Just wanted to explain where the error might come from. You are absolutely right in pointing it (heck, I overlooked that too!).

Answer (score 1):

You should clone your array instead. I copied this from John Resig [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object/122704#122704). See his post for more explanation.

```
// Shallow copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend({}, oldObject);

// Deep copy
var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject);
```

This should work for your `arr` and `new_arr`.

Answer (score -1):

may be because arr is an object and 
    var new_arr = arr
just assigns reference to it to new_arr ?  try this 
    new_arr = arr.clone()

Comment: It says arr.clone is not a function